# How to display xml with two parent nodes

Tags: java, xml

How to generate xml using dom parser in java , as shown below

```
<result>
       <schma_index>
         <id>8</id>
         <name>raja</name>
       <schma_index>
    </result>
```

Above should be display like

```
<Massage>No privilege</Mesaage>
<result>
   <schma_index>
     <id>8</id>
     <name>raja</name>
   <schma_index>
</result>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't have two root elements in xml. Read about [well-formed xml](http://www.javacommerce.com/displaypage.jsp?name=wellform.sql&id=18238). You can however generate `Message` and `result` xml's separately and then concatenate them. However, the parser's can't parse the result xml.

Answer (score 0):

In a "Valid" XML, there can be only one root element. [As per this specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-well-formed):"There is exactly one element, called the root, or document element, no part of which appears in the content of any other element."

So, you have two options:

1. create two seperate xml files - one containing Message and other results
2. enclose Message & Results with some other root element:

i.e,

```
<root>
    <Massage>No privillage</Mesaage>
    <result>
       <schma_index>
     <id>8</id>
     <name>raja</name>
       <schma_index>
    </result>
</root>
```